# Complexity of ByteSize() method

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

What is the complexity of the method `ByteSize()` for c++ protocol buffers? In other words, is the size calculated while I set parameters, and stored in the protocol buffer internally, or is the calculation done when I call `ByteSize()`. If the latter is the case this could be quite expensive for a large protocol buffer object right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seems to be hinted from documentation of other functions: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message

> `SpaceUsed()` is noticeably slower than `ByteSize()`, as it is implemented using reflection (rather than the generated code implementation for `ByteSize()`). **Like `ByteSize()`**, its CPU time is linear in the number of fields defined for the proto.

and

> `ByteSizeLong()` is generally linear in the number of fields defined for the proto.

I don't actually see a description for the complexity of `ByteSize()` itself though, just this:

> `int ByteSize() const`
>
> Legacy `ByteSize()` API.

So it seems to suggest you should be using one of the others.

Comment: Can I ask the difference between `ByteSizeLong()` and `ByteSize()`?